# Does Firebase change app key hash for Facebook?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-sdk-4.0

I connected Firebase Authentication and Facebook SDK as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login). I added key hash from my computer and signed in for first time in app and everything worked. So I decided to sign in again and I get error from Facebook that key hash is invalid and does not match stored key hashes. It turned out that this key hash which is shown in facebook error is not the same I get from my computer.

I copied this key hash to Facebook settings and now it's working, but how does it work for first time? It's really weird so I'm wondering if Firebase somehow changes key hash or something?